# How do I activesync my old phone information to a new phone?

Tags: activesync, windows-mobile-6

I need to activesync all my oldcontacts to a new phone, but can't see how to do it in the software. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the "sync" part should be the answer here, aren't your contacts already synced to your computer? Then just sync your new phone with your computer? If you don't have any syncing of contacts going on then you have to set up such a partnership between the computer and the old phone first I guess...

...basically when I replace a Windows Mobile phone all I do is set up the new one with ActiveSync and it will sync all data with whatever is holding it (local computer, server activesync and so on).

Answer (score -1):

I think best way is backup in the phone via SPB Backup and restore at new phone.

**SPB Backup**

- 14-days trial
- [web](http://www.spbsoftware.com/pocketpc-software/backup/)